# Minimize a function through its upper approximation

Tags: convex-optimization

I have some function $f(x) : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ (n is about several thousands, say $1000 \leq n \leq 10000$) to minimize over some constraints $g(x) \leq 0$ (by the way, $g$ is quadratic over $x$).

$f(x)$ is convex, differentiable (but not twice differentiable), nonnegative for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, but its formula is too complicated (from the computational point of view). Thus I'm not able to write down its derivatives and pass them to the solver (or I can but have a strong opinion that it will not work).

But: there is an upper approximation $F(x)$ such as $F(x) \geq f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ which is somewhat "close" to $f(x)$ (though it is not yet proved *how much close*) and its formula is much better and it is much more convenient to optimize, and it has derivatives of all degrees.

For which condition on the quality of approximation ($|F(x) - f(x)|$) the minimization of $F(x)$  will imply the minimization of $f(x)$?

Sorry if this seems too trivial! But I cannot easily figure out in what direction to dig this problem but at the same time have a strong feeling that it should be some commonly known problem.

UPDATE:

Both $f(x)$ and $F(x)$ are convex.

Comment: You could try to do line search where the descend direction is found using $F$ and the step size is found using $f$. Not sure however what the conditions on $F$ is for this to work and what the performance will be...

Answer (score 1):

If the derivatives are not known, you can use any constrained optimizer where the derivatives are approximated. Otherwise, I can recommended stochastic/blackbox/global optimization methods. The derivatives are not estimated and only function evaluations are needed.

But because your function is convex and has such a relatively high domain space, I would discourage stochastic optimization methods.

If it is not known how close $F(x)$ is to $f(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then you cannot imply that $x^* = argmin F(x) = argminf(x)$.

To answer your question: the minimization of $F(x)$ will imply the minimization of $f(x)$ if $|F(x)-f(x)| = 0$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

$F(x)$ can be quasiconvex, meaning it can have multiple local minima and the global minimum is not necessarily where the minima of $f(x)$ lies.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have forgotten to say that $F(x)$ is also convex. Can it help somehow?